# Shall I full recompile after .config modification?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

After compiling a kernel I've found that I want to touch certain .config constants.

I'm aware that these constants are used by source files from:

`drivers/hdi/`

`drivers/net/wireless/realtek`

So, I'm thinking, that maybe, I could only recompile those two directories, instead of the whole Linux kernel, but I'm not 100% sure

Which would be the protocol in this case?

1. Can I target `make clean` of only such directories?
2. Can I target a `make` of only such subdirectories?
3. Shall I execute a simple `make modules_install` to install those two modules?
4. Shall I do a `make install` after all, rewriting the current kernel installation? Or this must be done differently?